# How to store a boolean array and perform XOR operations in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to start using ElasticSearch to save some pre-computed results that I will need to match afterwards. This result is a 200-dimension bit array, associated with an id.

In order to perform the matching, I would need to perform an XOR operation between a search input, and the stored bitarrays for my existing elements, and sort on the number of bits that stay on (the cardinality).

Is it possible to do this at all, using Painless or other scripting strategies? And if it is, what would be the best mapping type to use to store this bitarray?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: that you should probably not store it as an array as the array elements are stored as nested objects. Additionally, indexed arrays do not respect the original order. So, you should opt to store it as a `keyword`.

Experimenting a bit and I think I found something that would work (you will have to experiment with your larger numbers to verify).

First: Index it as a `keyword` type, you will want to make sure that your `keyword` length specifies the appropriate max length.

```
"binary_string" :
   "type" : "keyword",
   "ignore_above" : 256 // <-- Whatever your max binary string length will be
}
```

Second: Then you can `sort` a query based on a scripted field using painless

```
GET binary_test/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": """
                def val1 = new BigInteger(doc['binary_string'].value, 2);
                val1.xor(new BigInteger("000000000", 2)).toString(2) // whatever your binary string is that you are comparing to
                """
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Considerations:

- The reason for sorting on the string value of the `xor` is that numbers are stored as `float` and eventual loss of precision may cost you.
- Constructing the two `BigInteger` values and using `BigInteger#xor` may be slower than simply iterating over the two strings and creating a new one your self, I would experiment with this if you are performance conscious.

If you don't care about the actual bit number, you could do the following, just be careful about bitarray length mismatch (if that is possible with your input)

```
"_script" : {
   "type" : "number",
       "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": """
                def val1 = doc['binary_string'].value;
                def val2 = "000000000"; // <-- the string you care about
                def count = 0;
                for(int i; i < val2.length; i++) {
                  if (val1.charAt(i) != val2.charAt(i)) {
                    count++;
                  }
                }
                count
                """
            },
```